# HtmlElements and Thucydides

Tags: thucydides, htmlelements

I want to use [HtmlElements](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements) with my test-project based on [Thucydides framework](https://github.com/thucydides-webtests/thucydides).
It's not clear where to start and how it can be used.

If I use it as in example in main project README, it does not populate elements without additional magic. Is there any examples or start guides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find required magic in [htmlelements-thucydides](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements/tree/master/htmlelements-thucydides) module. Long story short you just need to use BlockPageObject from the package above instead of PageObject provided by Thucydides. Here is a [working example](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements-examples/tree/master/htmlelements-thucydides-example) as well.